# Create a trigger to restrict any user to access the table EMP for modification on weekends

Tags: plsql, triggers

I have a table `emp` and fire a trigger which will prevent the access of some specific user on weekends. How do I obtain the current user?

I am unable to complete the trigger body as follows:

```
BEGIN
IF TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DAY')='SUNDAY' THEN....?
```

Answer (score 1):

So that comes down to:

1. Identifying the user doing the update
2. Preventing the update if it's user X

#### Identifying the user

According to [this article](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/before_update.php), you can use this code to get the user performing the `UPDATE`:

```
-- ...
DECLARE
   v_username varchar2(10);

BEGIN

   -- Find username of person performing UPDATE on the table
   SELECT user INTO v_username
   FROM dual;

-- ...
```

Here's their complete example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER orders_before_update
BEFORE UPDATE
   ON orders
   FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
   v_username varchar2(10);

BEGIN

   -- Find username of person performing UPDATE on the table
   SELECT user INTO v_username
   FROM dual;

   -- Update updated_date field to current system date
   :new.updated_date := sysdate;

   -- Update updated_by field to the username of the person performing the UPDATE
   :new.updated_by := v_username;

END;
```

#### Preventing the update

According to [this page](http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/85427), a trigger can call [`raise_application_error`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/errors.htm#sthref2006) to prevent an update.

Comment: @varshaDas: That's **just an example trigger**. I pointed out the relevant part above it.

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trr
after insert
   ON emp
   FOR EACH ROW


BEGIN

   if to_char(sysdate,'day')='monday' then
raise_application_error(20100,'you cannot access');
end if;

END;    I have written this code not getting appropriate ouput

Answer (score 1):

it seems you have given incorrect error code while  creating your exception, while executing your code got this error

`Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-21000: error number argument to raise_application_error of 20100 is out of range
ORA-06512: at "HR.TRR", line 1
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'HR.TRR'
21000. 00000 -  "error number argument to raise_application_error of %s%s is out of range"
*Cause:

*Action:   Use an error number in the range of -20000 to -20999, inclusive.`

While using a user defined exception your error code range should be in between
-20000 to -20999. Seems like you missed the '-' sign

Comment: trigger is getting created but still i am able to insert rows in emp table!